# Drop-down checkbox Works with fiddle, but not when saved as .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m8X7j/3/) works fine. But when i paste it into a notepad and saved as .html it is not working. WHY?

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    $("#mytable tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    });
    if($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0){
        $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
    }
    else{
        $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
    }
});
$("#selector").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
});
```

I am working on a drop-down checkbox. And it is an answer i found out.

Here is my html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Constrain movement</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<!-- Include the DropDownCheckList supoprt -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    $("#mytable tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    });
    if($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0){
        $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
    }
    else{
        $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
    }
});
$("#selector").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
});

    </script>



<style>
body 
{
}

.custom-select {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 93%;

}

.custom-select span {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 180px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

td 
{
        color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 180px;
             padding: 5px;   


}

.custom-select ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 99%;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.custom-select ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-select ul li:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #FFF;
}

.custom-select ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

h1, h2{
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;

}
.noborder{border:0;}
table {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }


         }

          table.tabular {
            FONT-SIZE: 13px;
            FONT-FAMILY: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
            COLOR: #336699;
         }

         table.tabular thead {
             COLOR: #ffffff;
             FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
         }

         table.tabular th{
            background-color:#E10EDA; <!-- Header colour -->
            padding: 4px;
         }

         table.tabular td {
            background-color:#B4D5D4; <!-- Column colour -->
            padding: 2px;
         }

</style>





</head>


<body>


<div id="dropdownframe"></div>

<div class="custom-select">
    <div id="selector"> <span>Select Option</span> </div>

</div>

<div id="main"  style="display: none" > 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="vehicle" value="0" /> Index</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Parameter Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="vehicle" value="2" /> Page Name</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    </table>
</div>

</div>


<TABLE  id="mytable"  style="width:510px" class="resizable tabular">

<THEAD>

<TR>

<TH class="index" style='width:60px'>Index</TH>

<TH class="param" style='width:170px'><span class="nowrap">Parameter Name</span></TH>

<TH class="page"  style='width:110px'><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></TH>



</TR>
</THEAD> 
<TBODY style="height:200px">
<TR>

<TD class="index">0</TD>
<TD class="param">1_2</TD>
<TD class="page">1_3</TD>


</TR>

<TR>

<TD class="index">0</TD>
<TD class="param">1_2</TD>
<TD class="page">1_3</TD>


</TR>

<TR>

<TD class="index">0</TD>
<TD class="param">1_2</TD>
<TD class="page">1_3</TD>


</TR>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me why? It will be really helpful.

Comment: You may not be importing JQuery library

Comment: Do you have a `js` folder in the same directory as the HTML file? You should also let us know what the error console is reporting.

Comment: put the script inside the document.ready().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    $("#mytable tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+val+")").toggle();
    });
    if($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0){
        $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
    }
    else{
        $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
    }
});
$("#selector").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
});

    </script>
```

fiddle will execute your code when the html is parsed so your javascript can access full html content

you write your code to  the browser will parse and execute when it meet the javascript

the problem here is simple: when your code in  executes, the html is not parsed by browser so it

can not find the element you need.

two ways to fix:

1.move your javascript code to the bottom of your body :  just before `</body>`

1. listener for the load event on window and put the javascript code into it in jquery you can do it as:

$(function () { // add here to wrapper the code

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
var val = $(this).val();    
$("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq("+val+")").toggle();
$("#mytable tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td:eq("+val+")").toggle();
});
if($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0){
    $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
}
else{
    $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
}
```

});
$("#selector").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
});

}); // add here

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to be in [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#mytable tr:first").find("th:eq(" + val + ")").toggle();
        $("#mytable tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td:eq(" + val + ")").toggle();
        });
        if ($("#mytable tr:first").find("th:visible").length > 0) {
            $("#mytable").removeClass("noborder");
        } else {
            $("#mytable").addClass("noborder");
        }
    });
    $("#selector").click(function () {
        $("#main").toggle();
        $("p").toggle();
    });
})
```

By default(second dropdown in the Frameworks and Extensions section of left panel) fiddle add the script in a `window.onload` handler like

```
window.onload = function(){
    //your code
}
```